# What I am doing wrong here, my style sheet is not loading up

Tags: html, css

I have created an external style sheet and name it style.css.

**style.css**

```css
#topbar
{
 background-color: red;
 width: 1000px;
 height: 40px;

}

body{
 background-color: green;
}
```

Now I am calling this style.css from the root folder but its not working. I copied the style.css on both within internal folder and on root but still not loading up.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>BBC News Site/title>

  

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">

  
    
</head>


<body>

 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you set up a plunker with your issue?

Comment: have you looked in inspector tools? it shows if css files 404 :)

Comment: Could you add the folder layout showing location of files?

Comment: not showing up style sheet on inspector tool too.. I am using sublime text 3 editor.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with this code. Use the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Network tab. Check that the request for the stylesheet is being made. Check the the response is the response you expect (i.e. has the right status code, content-type, and content in it). Look at the console. See if it shows any errors. Use [a makeup validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) to make sure there are no errors in the HTML. Use [a CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) too.

Comment: The title definition has an invalid end tag which might be causing the problem. Worth checking.

Comment: change <title>BBC News Site/title> to        <title>BBC News Site</title>

Comment: voting to close as a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<title>BBC News Site/title>
```

fix it into :

```
<title>BBC News Site</title>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, you nailed it... That is why I hate the css and html one little mistake and you spend hours into it. Thanks alot.

Comment: This is why we have tools to spot errors like that. https://validator.w3.org/nu/ and the DOM inspector in your browser.

Comment: @GustiArya Done. Thanks for the answer.